# How does one pass NULL named parameters to n1ql queries?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm using the .NET SDK.

Passing null as a string does not work and passing an actual null value throws the following exception:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Couchbase.N1QL.Error",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Exception",
  "StackTrace": null
}
```

I'm trying to build a query with optional search parameters where I pass nulls for parameters that the user did not decide to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that issue was related to another missing parameter.  This works for adding NULL named parameters using the .NET SDK.

```
queryRequest.AddNamedParameter(namedParameters.Key, null);
```